# How to set dynamic UIImageView height and also UITableViewCell height according to UIImageView height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, ios-autolayout

Want to set UIImageView size dynamically according to image size and also want to set UITableViewCell height according to above mentioned UIImageView height, which is in UITableViewCell using AutoLayout in Objective c.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

And my code under cellForRowAtIndexPath method is given below:

```
[cellRecImg.imgMessage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dictMessage objectForKey:@"msg_attachment"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-33"]];
CGFloat imageHeight = cellRecImg.imgMessage.image.size.height;
CGFloat imageWidth = cellRecImg.imgMessage.image.size.width;
float ratio = cellRecImg.imgMessage.frame.size.width / cellRecImg.imgMessage.frame.size.height;
float newHeight = imageHeight / ratio;
float newWidth = imageWidth / ratio;
cellRecImg.constImageHeight.constant = newHeight;
cellRecImg.constImageWidth.constant = newWidth;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

[This is my UITableViewCell's xib design where can you see the view' constant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5HXJ.png)
[This is my UIImageView, here you can see the constants of UIImageView's.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIJMb.png)
[This the result I got from simulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9H8t.png)

In this result Image you can see that UIImageView create lots of extra gaps form UIImage to UIImageView edge. Actually I don't want that gap and also want to set the UITableViewRow height dynamic according to UIImageView height.

**Please answer in Objective c language**

Comment: Just glancing it looks right. Click on the image and change the content hugging to 1000. Also do it on the sender testlabel.

Comment: Ok, but which content hugging should I change? Vertical or Horizontal or both?

Comment: @AnupamDas - first, you don't need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` if you're returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Second, you say *"set UIImageView size dynamically according to image size"* ... that's the code we need to see to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @DonMag - That's is not work for me, still searching for better option.

Comment: @AnupamDas - show the code you are using to set the `UIImageViewSize` "dynamically". I suspect your image view is set to `Aspect Fit` and your image is actually much taller than it appears in the view.

Comment: @DonMag - Yes I set it as Aspect Fit but I didn't set image view's size dynamically, as I did it in storyboard using autolayout which is already attached with my question.

Comment: @AnupamDas - that doesn't make sense... you say you are setting the size dynamically according to image size. So, show the code that is doing that. The pictures you've shown don't indicate anything about size constraints. To get help, you're going to need to show the code where you are changing the image.

Comment: @DonMag [cellRecImg.imgMessage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dictMessage objectForKey:@"msg_attachment"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-33"]];
CGFloat imageHeight=cellRecImg.imgMessage.frame.size.height;
CGFloat imageWidth=cellRecImg.imgMessage.frame.size.width;
float ratio=cellRecImg.imgMessage.image.size.width/cellRecImg.imgMessage.image.size.height;
float newHeight=imageHeight/ratio;
float newWidth=imageWidth/ratio;
cellRecImg.constImageHeight.constant=newHeight;
cellRecImg.constImageWidth.constant=newWidth;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: @AnupamDas - you're doing a couple things wrong. Mainly, `sd_setImageWithURL` is asynchronous, so when you follow it with `CGFloat imageHeight = cellRecImg.imgMessage.image.size.height;` you are getting the size of the *placeholder* image, not the image from the URL. I'd suggest searching on `sd_setImageWithURL uitableviewcell height` -- you'll find lots of results, because it's been done and discussed many times.